# Woocommerce Display Discount On cart

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

hi guys  i wanna show how much customers save with current deal. I entered regular and sale price for all products on my store and it show the percentage of discount on prdocut catalog.Woocommerce cart shows only the total and subtotal.

Subtotal:10$
Total:10$

so i wrote this function to show what i want. Although it works on my localhost, I can't get any results on live hosting.

```
 function discount_module_in() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $price=get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_regular_price', true);
            $sale=get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_sale_price', true);
            $amount=$price-$sale;
            $discount=(1-$sale/$price)*100;
            if (intval($discount)==70) {
                $amount70+=$amount;
            } 
            if (intval($discount)==50) {
                $amount50+=$amount;
            }
            if (intval($discount)==30) {
                $amount30+=$amount;

            }

        }
        if ($amount70>0) {
            echo "70% OFF: -".$amount70.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()."<br>";
        }
        if ($amount50>0) {
            echo "50% OFF: -".$amount50.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()."<br>";
        }
        if ($amount30>0) {
            echo "30% OFF: -".$amount30.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()."<br>";
        }


}   
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_totals', 'discount_module_in');
```

I also check if its theme issue or not but i just paste the code inside of fuction.php, to be ensure i try simple function and it worked. It's not a woocommerce hook issue either.

```
  function discount_module_in() {

        echo "test"
  }
  add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_totals', 'discount_module_in');
```

i also change my code with this. it eorken on local host but still not working on live host.

```
function deneme(){

    global $woocommerce;


    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    foreach( $cart as $cart_item ){

    $product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['product_id'] );


    $price=$product->get_regular_price();
    $sale=$product->get_sale_price();

    $amount=$price-$sale;
    $discount=(1-$sale/$price)*100;
        if (intval($discount)==70) {
            $amount70+=$amount;
        } 
        if (intval($discount)==50) {
                    $amount50+=$amount;
        }
        if (intval($discount)==30) {
        $amount30+=$amount;
        }

    }
        if ($amount70>0) {
            echo "70% OFF: -".$amount70.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()."<br>";
        }
        if ($amount50>0) {
            echo "50% OFF: -".$amount50.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()."<br>";
        }
        if ($amount30>0) {
            echo "30% OFF: -".$amount30.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()."<br>";
        }    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'deneme');
```

after debuggin it gives me this error

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in
>   /home/u693223509/domains/inuovo.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/inuovo/functions.php
>   on line 34
>
> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in
>   /home/u693223509/domains/inuovo.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/inuovo/functions.php
>   on line 34
>
> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in
>   /home/u693223509/domains/inuovo.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/inuovo/functions.php
>   on line 35
>
> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in
>   /home/u693223509/domains/inuovo.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/inuovo/functions.php
>   on line 35
>
> Warning: Division by zero in
>   /home/u693223509/domains/inuovo.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/inuovo/functions.php
>   on line 35

here are line 34 35

```
    $amount=$price-$sale;
    $discount=(1-$sale/$price)*100;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution; sorry for delay :) i hope this will help who looking for same issue;

```
    function deneme (){

    global $woocommerce;


    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    foreach( $cart as $cart_item ){

    $product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['product_id'] );
    // Now you have access to (see above)...

    $sale     =  $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true );
    $price  =  $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true );
    $amount=$price-$sale;
    $total+=$price*$cart_item['quantity'];
    $discount=(1-$sale/$price)*100;
        if (intval($discount)==70) {
            $amount70+=$amount*$cart_item['quantity'];
        } 
        if (intval($discount)==50) {
            $amount50+=$amount*$cart_item['quantity'];
        }
        if (intval($discount)==30) {
        $amount30+=$amount*$cart_item['quantity'];
        }

    }
        echo "<span style='float:right'>ORDER TOTAL: ".get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().$total."</span><br>";
        if ($amount70>0) {
            echo "<span style='float:right'>70% OFF: -".get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().$amount70."</span><br>";
        }
        if ($amount50>0) {
            echo "<span style='float:right'>50% OFF: -".get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().$amount50."</span><br>";
        }
        if ($amount30>0) {
            echo "<span style='float:right'>30% OFF: -".get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().$amount30."</span><br>";
        }  
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_order_total', 'deneme');
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution im sorry its my bad my shop based on variable produts, after i call variation price it worked!

Comment: Hi, welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange. We generally prefer answers to be fairly definitive. Could I suggest you show the code that worked and maybe explain how you worked it out so that others can follow along who have a similar issue?